# Create Regex by string "\" character java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have to read a file with some String values and transform them to Regex. So I am using the class `Pattern` of `java.util.regex` and I have some problem for some special characters.

For example if I have this String:

```
*Hello
```

when I am creating the regex with:

```
Pattern.compile("*Hello").matcher("*Hello").matches()
```

the result is false.

So I need to find a way to transform automatically the String in the compile in `\\*Hello`. How is it possible?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: Are you looking for the `Pattern.quote` method, perhaps?

Comment: I don't think is the same: quote doesn’t escape the string itself, but wraps it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "wrap" here, but it does achieve what I thought your aim was - `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("*Hello")).matcher("*Hello").matches()` returns true. Does it matter whether that's via adding backslashes or a different means?